# How do you update individual properties of objects in React component states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple React app that allows the user to add contacts to a master list. My components state looks like this:

```
state = {
        contact: {
            fname: "",
            lname: "",
            address: "",
            phone: "",
            email: "",
            id: ""
        }
    };
```

So far, I have been able to effectively add properties such as name, email, etc using values sent from inputs.

```
this.setState({
    contact: {
        ...this.state.contact,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value // e is an event sent from an input
    }
});
    };
```

That's all fine and dandy, but I need each contact to have a unique ID. I have been trying to tack on the ID to the contact object before I send it up the component hierarchy.

```
const unId = new Date().getTime();
this.setState({
    contact: {
        ...this.state.contact,
        id: unId
    }
});
```

This code is producing some strange issues and I'm not sure why. When I run it for the first time, the id is generated, but **not assigned** to the contact. The second time I run it, the id produced the **first time** is assigned to the **second** contact. In other words, the id property is updating the state later one cycle behind the time it should.

I'm not very familiar with synchronicity or anything in React, so I would really appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: Sounds like you are examining your state right after setting it, instead of inside the has updated callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this example help you? If not, can you comment what do you exactly want?

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mccarthy-7i69e

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    contact: {
      fname: "",
      lname: "",
      address: "",
      phone: "",
      email: "",
      id: new Date().getTime()
    }
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      contact: {
        ...this.state.contact,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    const { fname, lname, address, phone, email, id } = this.state.contact;

    return (
      <div>
        <label>fname</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={fname}
          name="fname"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <label>lname</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={lname}
          name="lname"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
          <br />
        <label>address</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={address}
          name="address"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
          <br />
        <label>phone</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={phone}
          name="phone"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
          <br />
        <label>email</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={email}
          name="email"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
          <br />
        <label>id</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={id}
          name="id"
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <hr />
        {
          JSON.stringify(this.state)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! On a side note, the structure and naming conventions you used are scarily similar to my file. So close I thought I put my full file for a second.

Answer (score 0):

The ID isn't created until the next render because the component's state isn't initialized when it gets created. You need to initialize its state.

Either in a class constructor

```
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        id: new Date().getTime()
      }
    }
```

or a state attribute

```
    state = {
      id: new Date().getTime()
    }
```

Here is a [working codepen example](https://codepen.io/brietsparks/pen/QWWgqgw)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution. I accepted the other answer because it came first, but I appreciate it. I *also* upvoted it, but I don't have enough rep for it to show.